# Developing a real time collaborative drawing system

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, websocket, raphael

I am interested in making a realtime collaborative drawing system similar to  http://flockdraw.com/ . However I would like to only use open source tools (flockdraw uses flash and also limits the number of users) and also I will host it myself.

I have been considering writing the whole thing in Java. However I realize I am not up to date with recent advances in programming languages/libraries.  What would be a good programming language/library combination to do this task?

**Update.** This [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845682/real-time-collaborative-drawing-whiteboard-in-html5-js-and-websockets?rq=1) looks very relevant.

Comment: Take a look at [meteor](https://www.meteor.com/)

Comment: You can check the source of https://github.com/lovasoa/whitebophir, an opensource collaborative whiteboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See:

- [Realtime HTML5 Canvas Drawing with WebSockets, Node.JS & Socket.io](http://wesbos.com/html5-canvas-websockets-nodejs/) - all open source
- [draw](https://github.com/byrichardpowell/draw) similar technologies to the above
- [node.js drawing game tutorial](http://tutorialzine.com/2012/08/nodejs-drawing-game/)

The basic principles for this is generally pretty easy. Just communicate the shape that has been drawn to the other users - as you suggest. With that in mind there are a number of open source [realtime web technologies](http://www.leggetter.co.uk/real-time-web-technologies-guide) that you could use.

Comment: This is an excellent example and starting points.  Good job Phil!

Answer (score 1):

I've seen apps like that using HTML5.

Take a look at this [app](http://www.unionplatform.com/?page_id=2762). I think it can help you get started.

This kind of apps usually take advantage of HTML5 Canvas and probably HTML5 WebSockets. There are lots of libraries and tutorials out there.

Comment: Thanks that looks really helpful. Is the example you gave entirely open source?

Comment: It doesn't seem like it, sorry. Heres a tutorial as well http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/304066-html5-canvas-collaboration/

Comment: Thanks again. I am not sure why you need to use mysql (or any database) for this task but there is plenty to read up on.