# How to implement an online whiteboard facility?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, flash, frontend, backend

I am planning to implement an online whiteboard. But I have no idea where to start. I went through many creative applications online, most of them seemed to have been implemented using Adobe Flash. Can anyone provide ideas on how to start off with the application regarding both the front-end and back-end implementation.

Answer (score 3):

As a web developer I would suggest you to look at HTML5 Canvas as it allows you to draw/scribble on it. You must consider using [fabric js](http://fabricjs.com/) So you would need HTML5 and javascript.

To share your whiteboard scribbling or anything you ll have to push real time data to other clients/user(aka browser), you should consider [websockets](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/) , [socket.io](http://socket.io/)

Here [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845682/real-time-collaborative-drawing-whiteboard-in-html5-js-and-websockets) question can you help you I think. That should get you started. Let us know if you face any specific problem.